# find minDistance parameter in requestlocationupdates is used?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am working with location features in android. I have found `requestlocationupdates()` in LocationManager that can help me in tracking the users location.

Can anyone please help me to find how the minDistance is used in this function?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: [Clarification on min distance on LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates method, min Distance parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354512/clarification-on-min-distance-on-locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-method)

> Essentially this means that if the platform observes your current position as being more than minDistance from the last location that was saved by the platform, your listener will get notified with the updated position. Note that these two positions don't necessarily need to be sequential (i.e., there could be a number of small displacements that eventually add up to minDistance, and the location that finally exceeds the threshold will be the one reported to the app).

And I really recommend you to look into FusedLocationProviderApi that is part of Google Services: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi